# Inserting list of objects as distinct Mongo documents with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have a `dataset` that looks like this:

```
[{
    "myhost1.com": {
        "services": [
            {
                "environment": "prod", 
                "__module__": "polling_functions", 
                "serviceName": "service-a", 
                "__class__": "app"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "myhost2.com": {
        "services": [
            {
                "environment": "prod", 
                "__module__": "polling_functions", 
                "serviceName": "service-a", 
                "__class__": "db"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    ...
```

What I want to do is insert each of these as a separate document in my MongoDB. After cleansing the keys to remove `.` characters, I've tried two inserts:

`db.hostuse.insert_many(dataset)`

and

```
for key in dataset[0]:
    db.hostuse.insert_one(dataset[0][key])
```

Neither of these accomplish what I want though. The first inserts a single document, with keys being the hostnames. The second inserts multiple documents, but without the hostnames; instead, every key is `services`.

How can I transform this dataset so that I can pass it to my MongoDB, and result in multiple documents, each with the key of `hostname`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
collection = MongoClient().db.collection
for hostname, services in dataset[0].items():
    collection.insert_one({'hostname': hostname,
                           'services': services})
```

You need to pull the dict out of dataset[0] and for each key and value in the dict, insert a separate document.

Comment: This mostly works, but is storing the document as: `{
       "_id" : ObjectId("584f175ee281af385ce8a6bc"),

       "services" : {

               "services" : [

                       {

                               ...
                       }

               ]

       },

       "hostname" : "myhost1.com"

}` -- note the duplicate "services" key/field.

Comment: For my purposes, since I can assume a single `services` section exists within each `host` section, changing the code to use `({'hostname': hostname, services.keys()[0]: services.values()[0]})` worked for me